# Angular 9 - how to test a service that calls navigateByUrl by mocking the router

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-router

All the examples I can find only show how to test a component that calls a navigateByUrl. I have a service that does it:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BreadcrumbService {
  constructor(private router: Router, private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  /**
   * Return a array of current path
   *
   */
  getCurrentRouterPath(): Array<string> {
    return this.router.url.split('/').filter(path => path);
  }
}
```

I am trying to test it by mocking the Router:

```
import {TestBed, async, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {BreadcrumbService} from './breadcrumb.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

class MockRouter {
  navigateByUrl(url: string) {
    return { url };
  }
}

describe('BreadcrumbService', () => {
  let service: BreadcrumbService;
  let activateRoute: ActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute }
    ]
    });
    activateRoute = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
    service = TestBed.inject(BreadcrumbService);
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return an array of route path', inject([Router], (router: MockRouter) => {
      const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');
      router.navigateByUrl('/giveaway/all');
      const arrayPath = service.getCurrentRouterPath();
      expect(arrayPath).not.toBeNull();
      expect(arrayPath).not.toBeUndefined();
      expect(arrayPath).toEqual(['giveaway', 'all']);    
  }));
});
```

...but the url is always undefined, hence `cannot read property 'split of undefined occurs.`

**What I tried**

So I decided to mock the url property itself to avoid that:

```
class MockRouter {
  private _url = '';
  get url(): string {
      return this._url;
  }
  set url(value: string) {
      this._url = value;
  }
}
```

Now the test runs, but the url property is always empty, so I get an empty array back and so the test fails.

OK, so I can make this pass by explicitly setting the url directly on the mock, but this seems wrong to me as it is completely skipping the navigate step (as you notice I removed the `navigateByUrl` from the mocked class):

```
  it('should return an array of route path', inject([Router], (router: MockRouter) => {
      router.url = '/giveaway/all';
      const arrayPath = service.getCurrentRouterPath();
      expect(arrayPath).not.toBeNull();
      expect(arrayPath).not.toBeUndefined();
      expect(arrayPath).toEqual(['giveaway', 'all']);    
  }));
```

So there are 3 questions here really:

1. Should I NOT be mocking the router and actually inject the real router and actually trigger a navigate event in the test? (tried that, it never fails! - see the note below)
2. Does (1) matter if I just go with what works above since it does actually test the method in the service?
3. Should I even need to test this method since all it actually depends on are other things that are tested by other developers already (ie the Angular router, the array split and filter).

**NOTE**

I inherited the code and it was originally like the below, where the test never fails:

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {BreadcrumbService} from './breadcrumb.service';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';

describe('BreadcrumbService', () => {
  let service: BreadcrumbService;
  let router: Router;
  let activateRoute: ActivatedRoute;
  let ngZone: NgZone;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])]
    });
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    activateRoute = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
    service = TestBed.inject(BreadcrumbService);
    ngZone = TestBed.inject(NgZone);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should receive a array of route path', () => {
    ngZone.run(() => {
      router.navigateByUrl('/giveaway/all').then(() => {
        const arrayPath = service.getCurrentRouterPath();
        expect(arrayPath).not.toBeNull();
        expect(arrayPath).not.toBeUndefined();
        expect(arrayPath.length).toEqual(2);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

which **always passes regardless** of the length of the navigation you call or the equality test. So even this passes:

```
        expect(arrayPath.length).toEqual(200)
```

and this:

```
        expect(arrayPath.length).toEqual(0)
```

which seems very bizarre.

If anyone is able to explain why using the actual router and navigating did not work I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I need to test something that uses router, I try to mock as much as possible. Routing is always tricky when testing. When I look at your service, it does something really simple and can be tested regardless of navigation. So I would just test it as follows

```js
const testUrl = '/some/test/url';

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { 
          provide: Router, 
          useValue: {
            url: testUrl 
          } 
        }
    ]
    });
    activateRoute = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
    service = TestBed.inject(BreadcrumbService);
}));

it('should return an array of route path', () => {
  const arrayPath = service.getCurrentRouterPath();
  expect(arrayPath).not.toBeNull();
  expect(arrayPath).not.toBeUndefined();
  expect(arrayPath).toEqual(['some', 'test', 'url']);    
}));
```

Your test should not care about how the `url` is set. That is someone else's job. You should assume `Router` is well tested and `url` is properly set upon navigation. Otherwise, our tests become too complex to write and maintain.

To answer your other question, why the test always passes

Running async code within `it` may result in unexpected behavior. Your test always passes because the test finishes before async function executes. So, `expect....` executes when the test is already done (and passed). To hold the test until you run your code, you can use `done` as follows

```js
it('should receive a array of route path', (done) => {
    ngZone.run(() => {
      router.navigateByUrl('/giveaway/all').then(() => {
        const arrayPath = service.getCurrentRouterPath();
        expect(arrayPath).not.toBeNull();
        expect(arrayPath).not.toBeUndefined();
        expect(arrayPath.length).toEqual(2);

        done(); // mark the test as done 
      });
    });
});
```

For more info about testing async functions, you can read it [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async#callbacks)

Comment: @rmcsharry was `done` the missing part of your tests? when you used `done`, the test failed right?